# How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap and jQuery in Android?

Tags: jquery, android, soap, cordova

I am trying to invoke a web service in my PhoneGap app using jQuery.
Is this possible using jQuery in PhoneGap? If it is then share some small example...
Any help would be greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient