# Call a SOAP based web-service using JQuery in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery, cordova

I have a big problem regarding to call a web-service through **Jquery**.

I am developing one **phonegap application** same as **Android application** right now.In that I have to call a web-service and fetch data from there.I tried to solve it in my way but i didn't find proper solution.

My **web-service** is built in **.NET using SOAP**. And now i want to call that web-service through my **HTML page using jquery**. So, Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some links I got from research

[Google group phonegap group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/i1iyoWRqu0k)

[Blackberry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-call-soap-based-web-service-in-phone-gap/td-p/1909183)

[Another google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/3xzY5B7cXPk)

Following are some stack overflow question-answers which may can solve your problem ,

[How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974295/how-call-soap-based-web-service-using-phonegap-in-iphone)

[How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap and jQuery in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383265/how-call-soap-based-web-service-using-phonegap-and-jquery-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLHttpRequest to connect with external domain 
this  is the sample code

```
      function connectXml()
        {
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
             var wsUrl="http://www.somedomain.com/servicexml"
     request.open("POST", wsUrl, true);
     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState == 4) {
     if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
     var data = request.responseText;

                alert(request.responseText);
                }}}}
```

Note:Give access to the domain in config.xml eg:access origin="http://somedmain.com".
     Add user INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml eg:"uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/uses-permission"